# Disable USB keyboard wakeup

Tags: 12.04, usb, power-management

With the update from 11.04 to 12.04, my USB keyboard activity will wake Ubuntu from 'suspend'.  I'd like to disable this.  (My battery went dead due to some unexpected keyboard activity.)  This didn't happen in 11.04.

These links talk about USB power ctrl:

http://azitech.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/usbcore-autosuspend/
 http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1968487
 https://askubuntu.com/questions/165050/usb-wake-not-working-correctly
 http://www.ehow.com/how_7536984_configure-power-usb-ubuntu.html
 http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/miscellaneous/98253-turn-off-power-usb-port.html
 http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/howdoi-turn-on-off-usb-light-by-time-514863/
 http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/power-off-usb-509328/
 http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=853179
 http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1446965

The USB PwrMan doc: http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/usb/power-management.txt

Unfortunately, none offer a solution for me.

All my `/sys/bus/usb/devices/usbx/wakeup` are set to **disable**.  When you get the actual device, those are set to **enabled**, and are not editable.

```
$ cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
EHC1  S3  *enabled  
EHC2  S3  *enabled
```

Is there another way to disable USB wakeup?

Answer (score 8):

You can toggle the enabled/disabled state of each device in `/proc/acpi/wakeup` by writing the device name into that file. For my system (Debian, not Ubuntu) I have the following in my `/etc/rc.local` to do this:

```
# Disable USB wakeups caused by (un)plugging new devices. Otherwise the hub in
# my USB monitor causes my PC to wake up when I turn the monitor off.
for device in EHC1 EHC2 XHC
do
    if grep -q "$device.*enabled" /proc/acpi/wakeup
    then
        echo $device > /proc/acpi/wakeup
    fi
done
```

Comment: `/etc/rc.local` doesn't exists on my computer on  ubuntu 18, I put this file content to `/etc/init.d/keyboard-script` then ran `sudo update-rc.d keyboard-script defaults`, now this script will run on every boot

Answer (score 0):

I've seen options for this in my BIOS. Maybe try setting it there instead of in the OS?